# Why does bash show the expansion when using !$ etc.?

Tags: bash

If I type

```
mkdir my_new_directory_with_a_long_name
cd !$
```

I get

```
cd my_new_directory_with_a_long_name
```

output to the terminal, and then the cd command is run

Why does bash show this expansion and is there any way to turn it off?

Comment: Guessing it is so you know what has been run.

Answer (score -1):

This is part of the history expansion feature - !$ expands the to the last argument of the last command - disable history expansion with `set +H`

Comment: I don't want to disable the expansion, I'm just curious as to why the expansion is printed to stdout and if that can be disabled

Comment: how would you know what was run without the echo? I don't know if the echo can be disabled

Comment: That is true, however similarily, variable expansion is not shown, ie `cd $DIR` would not echo the expansion